# Android (native java) - Sliding Drawer - Content (Imageview and Checkbox) click event not firing

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

In one of the project,we have a sliding panel from the bottom. In which user can choose the checkbox and click the image inside the panel. so i have added a sliding drawer component inside the relative layout. Top view will contain, listview and the bottom it will be a slidingdrawer.

We have the handle and content part for the sliding component. Inside the content i have added a checkbox and imageview. I want to listen for those events when user clicks any one of those. I can able to listen for teh sliding drawer events but not the other two click events.

DO i miss anything for listening of events inside content part in the sliding drawer. I tried by adding clickable property to true in layout xml. But still the same result.

I searched in google, but not able to find the solution.

Please let me know, if i am missing anything.

```
<SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:handle="@+id/handle" android:content="@+id/content"
                android:animateOnClick="true" android:padding="15dp" android:topOffset="250dp" android:allowSingleTap="true"
                >
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/handle" android:background="@drawable/popbg" android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp" android:paddingRight="20dp">
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="text1" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:layout_weight="1"/>
                        <ImageView 
                            android:id="@+id/elrattSlidingIcon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/non_expand" android:layout_gravity="right"/>    
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/content" android:paddingLeft="15dp" android:paddingRight="14dp"
                        android:clickable="true">
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="top" android:padding="0dp"
                            android:clickable="true">
                            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:paddingTop="15dp" android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:background="@drawable/bg_elratt">
                                <ImageView android:id="@+id/elrattListBtmBtn"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/skickaintr_ov" android:clickable="true"/>
                                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal" android:paddingLeft="50dp" android:paddingRight="50dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="10dp">
                                    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/usrOption" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="0.2" android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector" android:tag="1"
                                        android:clickable="true"/>
                                    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:text="test2" android:singleLine="false"
                                        android:layout_weight="0.8"/>
                                </LinearLayout>                                 
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </SlidingDrawer>
```

Thanks in Advance,
Regards
Srini

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem is. Not sure whether this is the correct one. But it works for me.

I removed the immediate linearlayout after slidingdrawer component. Which i have added as a wrapper layer. After this i am able to listen to the events normally without any other changes. It was working as usual.

Thanks

Regards

Srinivasan